# Movie where people on seizure medication find out they are aliens

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

This movie was made in the last 15 years or so.

A high school girl and other random people are on seizure medication, and at a certain age get bumps on their foreheads. They somehow find out that they are human form of aliens which are small worm like creatures. Their race passed by Earth in a tiny black space ship the appearance and size of a large black sea urchin and somehow infect 2 men is a space station. They somehow attempt to rejoin their race. At one point a girl who is a member of their race in human form walks into a pond.

It was a very strange movie, but I would like to see it again. Google can't find it.

Comment: Is it the Final Days of Planet Earth? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478073/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl Or Slither? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0439815/plotsummary

Comment: Sounds like it could be an episode from Outer Limits

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it!

["Earthling", 2010](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1398999/)

> After a mysterious atmospheric event, a small group of people wake up to realize that their entire lives have been a lie. They are in fact aliens disguised as humans. Now they have to make a choice. Live amongst men, or try to find a way back home